# The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

There really is a lot of info about this problem in internet, but nothing is helped me.

That is my client code:

```
var token = $('form[action="/Storage/AddReceipt"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();


var addAntiForgeryToken = function(data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = token;
    return data;
};
var success = function (result) {
    alert(result.success);
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddReceipt", "Storage")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: addAntiForgeryToken({ Number: 1, BatchDate: '24/03/2015' }),
    success: success,
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddReceipt(...) {...}
```

and server response to my requerst -

> The required anti-forgery form field
>   "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

but correct token is sending:

### [image]

```
return JSON.stringify(data);
```

and

```
$.ajax({
            ...
            data: $('form[action="/Storage/AddReceipt"]').serialize(), 
            ...
            }
```

doesnt help too.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add the `__RequestVerificationToken` to the request `headers`. Add it as follows.

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("AddReceipt", "Storage")',
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
headers:{__RequestVerificationToken : token},
data: JSON.stringify(addAntiForgeryToken({ Number: 1, BatchDate: '24/03/2015' })),
success: success,
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
});
```

We must add the anti forgery token to the request `header`.

Comment: See my updated code, try as `JSON.stringify(addAntiForgeryToken({ Number: 1, BatchDate: '24/03/2015' }))`

Comment: @АкмальСалихов While setting the `contentType` as `application/json`, we should stringify the data to be passed to the server. please try the above whether it is helpful.

Comment: Ok, But I suspect the  `contentType` might be the cause, have to tried by removing it?